# How can i Post the json data with Nested arraylist using webapi

Tags: json.net, wcf-web-api

I want return the list data in json formate.I have Two poco classes (Order,Items) using these poco classes i want retun the data into json format

Sample Json formate what i want return using webapi.

```
        {"order":{
          "LocationId":1,
           "Amount":"7.79",
          "OrderContactEmail":"test@gmail.com",
          "OrderContactName":"test",
        "items":[{"Options":"y",
       "UnitCost":"7.79",
       "Quantity":"1","MenuItemId":"68"}],
       "DeviceIdentifier":"000000000000000",
        "ShipMethod":"PICK UP",
       "PickupDate":"2011-11-22 15:52:00",
       "OrderContactPhone":"123456"},
        "items":[{"Options":"y",
        "UnitCost":"7.79",
        "Quantity":"1","MenuItemId":"68"}],
        "DeviceIdentifier":"000000000000000",
         "ShipMethod":"PICK UP",
         "PickupDate":"2011-11-22 15:52:00",
         "OrderContactPhone":"123456"}}
```

Answer (score 2):

Pasting your wanted JSON into http://json2csharp.com you'll get this:

```
public class Item
{
    public string Options { get; set; }
    public string UnitCost { get; set; }
    public string Quantity { get; set; }
    public string MenuItemId { get; set; }
}

public class Order
{
    public int LocationId { get; set; }
    public string Amount { get; set; }
    public string OrderContactEmail { get; set; }
    public string OrderContactName { get; set; }
    public Item[] items { get; set; }
    public string DeviceIdentifier { get; set; }
    public string ShipMethod { get; set; }
    public string PickupDate { get; set; }
    public string OrderContactPhone { get; set; }
}

public class Item2
{
    public string Options { get; set; }
    public string UnitCost { get; set; }
    public string Quantity { get; set; }
    public string MenuItemId { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public Order order { get; set; }
    public Item2[] items { get; set; }
    public string DeviceIdentifier { get; set; }
    public string ShipMethod { get; set; }
    public string PickupDate { get; set; }
    public string OrderContactPhone { get; set; }
}
```

This should point you the direction...

You could also use some anonymous types this way:

```
var items = new Item[] {
    item1,
    item2
}

var json = new {
    order = new {
            LocationId = 1
            Items = items
        }
}
```

etc. etc.

Comment: How can I append Items in order array ?